# Не могу получить href

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет у меня такая проблема.
По мне я должен из каждый страницы получить href, div class="b" из тега  но получаю пустой список если кто может помогите.

````
def init_driver():
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver
def lookup(driver, timeout):
    links_page2=[]
    driver.get("https://www.tours.com/tours_vacations/ireland_(eire).htm")
    scroll_pause_time = timeout
    while True:
        for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class=b]//a'):
            links_page2.append('https://www.tours.com'+ str(i.get_attribute('href')))
        try:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next")))
            element.click()
        except:
            return links_page2

driver = init_driver()
links_page2=lookup(driver, timeout=5)
driver.quit()```
````

Comment: Код с `links_page2.append` вызывается?

Comment: @gil9red не знаю, как проверить ?

Comment: Отладчиком или банально добавить по всему коду `print`'ы и смотреть что вывело, а что нет. А так, скорее всего, у вас `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class=b]//a')` ничего не нашел

Comment: @gil9red в теле цикла for я сделал print(i) и ответа не было

Comment: Вооот, а если бы вы написали `print(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class=b]//a'))`, то стопудов получили бы `[]`, т.е. пустой список. Значит, либо вы неправильный xpath написали и/или тех элементов нет

Comment: @gil9red да так и есть поменял на это ```driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.b>a')``` и сработало спасибо тебе ))

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите сами это как ответ :)

Comment: Кст, возможно помогло бы с таким `xpath`: `//div[@class="b"]/a`, но вариант с css-селектором выглядит симпотичнее

Comment: @gil9red да может быть, мне тоже сss селектор понравился )

Answer (score 1):

Поменял это `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class=b]//a')`
на это `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.b>a')` и сработало ))